# How to automatically get a Add-on folder's path regardless of OS?

Tags: python, add-on, path

In Blender, is there a command to query what's the current path to the Add-on folder - regardless of what system I'm using?

Answer (score 12):

Ah, got it.

Paste this to the Python Console to get your add-ons path:

```
bpy.utils.user_resource('SCRIPTS', "addons")
```

Also see [the wiki](https://www.blender.org/manual/installing_blender/directorylayout.html).

Comment: Note, there can be multiple addon's directories (3 infact) UsersHome/UserPrefs/BlenderDefault. The example you give will only give the user's home directory addon path, which might not even exist.

Comment: Oh, good to know.
I guess they're listed here: https://www.blender.org/manual/installing_blender/directorylayout.html

Answer (score 11):

If you want to know the directory of the currently-executing addon, try this:

```
import os

script_file = os.path.realpath(__file__)
directory = os.path.dirname(script_file)
```

This is especially useful if your addon is a Python package, because it tells you which is the relevant subdirectory.

Answer (score 2):

Blender **addon utils** module can fetch the path of any given addon name if installed.

```
#iterate through all the addon name installed
#if The Addon Name exists then: 
#.__file__ will give away the file path where it is installed
#We are printing the file path in console
#If the given name does not exist it will pass

import bpy
import addon_utils

for mod in addon_utils.modules():
    if mod.bl_info['name'] == "The Addon Name":
        filepath = mod.__file__
        print (filepath)
    else:
        pass
```