# How to get the addons path using python?

Tags: python

How to get the value of this variable ?

[image]

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/20850/how-to-automatically-get-a-add-on-folders-path-regardless-of-os  pretty much `module.__file__`  ... eg `import some_addon` then `print(some_addon.__file__}`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

An add-on is just a regular *python module* so there are  [multiple ways to get the actual path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/247770/how-to-retrieve-a-modules-path).

You can use `addon_utils`, a module for addon management that comes with blender to filter the add-on and get the path:

```
import addon_utils
for mod in addon_utils.modules():
    print(mod.bl_info.get("name"))
    print(mod.__file__)
```

Or you can iterate through all *enabled addons* and use `sys.modules` dict:

```
import bpy
import sys

context = bpy.context

for mod_name in context.preferences.addons.keys():
    mod = sys.modules[mod_name]
    print(mod.__file__)
```

Related: [How can I get a list of the installed addons using the API?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/2797/31447)

Comment: Do you happen to know how to get the path to the adonns, knowing only the N-panel ?
![image](https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/31005234/111393849-9a967700-86ca-11eb-8ab6-840ed6e7c5c5.png)

Answer (score 2):

Blender **addon utils** module can fetch the path of any given addon name if installed.

```
#iterate through all the addon name installed
#if The Addon Name exists then: 
#.__file__ will give away the file path where it is installed
#We are printing the file path in console
#If the given name does not exist it will pass

import bpy
import addon_utils

for mod in addon_utils.modules():
    if mod.bl_info['name'] == "The Addon Name":
        filepath = mod.__file__
        print (filepath)
    else:
        pass
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the post. This site is not a regular forum, answers should be substantial and thoroughly explain the solution and required workflow. One liners and code without context rarely make for a good answer. If you can [edit] your post and provide some more details about the procedure and why it works feel free to restore it, otherwise it may be deleted or converted into a comment. See [How do I write a good answer?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer)